# Possible to create text box in Java Console?

Tags: java, netbeans, console, output, println

I'd like to output a line of text with a box in the Java console but I can't find any code that is able to do so.

I am familiar with println() and but I am not trying to create a UI with JOptionPane.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Not quite clear. Do you want to use UI (JOptionPane) or not?

Comment: I don't want to use a UI, my apologies if I haven't made it clear, @ArtemNovikov .

Comment: Right, but what does "with a box" mean in this context?

Comment: @currently_procrastinating Then you can't create any sort of UI inside console. Console is a console, and UI is UI. In console you can only make areas with special symbols like ******* or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean making a box within the console, you need to use a special character and use for loops. You need to provide values for rows and columns somehow before this.
Example:
          for(m=1;m<=rows;m++){
      for(c=1;c<=rows;c++){
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();

Here I used "*", but _ ,-, etc. can work as well. If you mean dialog box then I would use JOptionPane, other than that I can't help.